# how to call database from zend Framework forms in php

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have the following php script now i want to put his script in zend forms Here is my code so far :-

```
$parents = array();
$childs = array();
foreach ($this->Tagkey as $aResultDataValue) {
        $parents [$aResultDataValue['parent']] = $aResultDataValue['parent'];
        $childs [$aResultDataValue['parent']][] = $aResultDataValue['child'];
}

foreach ($parents as $parent) {
     echo '<div>';
     $parent_value = "'$parent'";
     echo '<div><input type="checkbox" name="parents[]" value="'.$parent.'" id="'.$parent.'" class="parentCheck"/>
     <label for="parents_'.$parent.'">'.$parent.'</label></div>';
         foreach ($childs[$parent] as $child) {
           $child_value = "'$child'";
               echo '<div style="margin-left:15px;"><input type="checkbox" name="childs[]" value="'.$child.'" id="childs_'.$child.'" class="child_'.$parent.'" onclick="checkParent('.$parent_value.','.$child_value.');"/>
              <label for="childs_'.$child.'">'.$child.'</label></div>';
     }
     echo '</div>';
}
```

now i am going to use this pure php script in zend form what i am trying is here :-

class Admin_Form_Users extends Zend_Form
{

```
public function init()
{   

   $parents = array();
      $childs = array();

      foreach ($this->Tagkey as $result) {
        $parents [$result['parent']] = $result['parent'];
        $childs [$result['parent']][] = $result['child'];
        }

       foreach ($parents as $parent) {

       $subForm = new Zend_SubForm();
       $subForm->addElement($parent);

       foreach ($children as $child) {
           $subForm->addElement($child);
       }

       $form->addSubForm($subForm);
    }      


        $parent = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
        $parent->addElements(array(
            new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('subscriptions', array(
                'label'        =>
                    'Which parent would you like to subscribe to?',
                'multiOptions' => $parents,
                'required'     => true,
                'filters'      => array('StringTrim'),
                'validators'   => array(
                    array('InArray',
                          false,
                          array(array_keys($parents)))
                )
            )),
        ));

        $child = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
        $child->addElements(array(
            new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('subscriptions', array(
                'label'        =>
                    'Which child would you like to subscribe to?',
                'multiOptions' => $childs,
                'required'     => true,
                'filters'      => array('StringTrim'),
                'validators'   => array(
                    array('InArray',
                          false,
                          array(array_keys($childs)))
                )
            )),
        ));


         $this->addSubForms(array(

        '$child' => $child,
        'parent' => $parent
    ));
```

I got an error

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/dashboard_campaign/application/modules/admin/forms/Users.php on line 19
```

means here :- `foreach ($this->Tagkey as $aResultDataValue) {`

`Tagkey` comes from database model

what i can do an I am `newbie` in zend framework what i am doing wrong help me

Comment: What is the output of `Zend_Debug::dump($this->Tagkey);`

Comment: @emaillenin :) when i put Zend_Debug::dump($this->Tagkey); in my form i got NULL

Comment: @emaillenin :) when i put my above pure php script in phtml it works very fine and also got output for  Zend_Debug::dump($this->Tagkey); but i have the requirement to work in zend form only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$TagKey` is not a member of Zend_Form, and I don't see where it is being added to it.

You could either pass the model that TagKey comes from into the form's constructor, or in the form's `init()` method, you need to create an instance of the model and get the TagKey variable.

Here is how you can get it from your controller into the form object.

```
public function editAction()
{
    $tags = new Campaign_Model_DbTable_Tag();
    $aResultData = $tags->getTagkey();
    $this->view->Tagkey = $aResultData;

    $form = new Admin_Form_Users($aResultData);

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
            // valid
        } else { 
            // errors 
        }
    }
}
```

Then add a constructor to your form.

```
// Admin_Form_Model
public function __construct($tagKey)
{   
    $this->tagKey = $tagKey;

    parent::__construct(); // you must call this last as it calls init()
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see.  Now you somehow need to get it into the Form.  Just using it in the controller doesn't do any good for the form object itself.

Comment: :) how can i do that please help me

Comment: In UserController on line 44 where you create the form object, you have to create it with the tagkey object like `$form = new Admin_Form_Users($aResultData);`

Comment: Then maybe $this->TagKey is not an array or iteratable object, try var_dump to see what it is.

Comment: NULL Warning: see my above comments also

Answer (score 0):

your problem is simple error:

you set up the variable `$childs = array();`
then called it as **$children**:

```
foreach ($children as $child) {
           $subForm->addElement($child);
       }
```

this may not be the only error in this script, but it's the one the message deals with.